# xbindkeys does not work. Terminated message

Tags: linux, key-bindings

I have xbindkeys among the commands to run on session start on my xinitrc.
Problem is, lately xbindkeys is not running.

All other programs on xinitrc run, so its not startx.

When I try running from console, (even with the -n non demon flag) the program exits immediately with the message `Terminated`

What could it be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a linux box at my finger tips to test these ideas with, but perhaps it doesn't like your $HOME/.xbindkeysrc file?

Running it from console with --verbose should give more details about the failure.

Comment: -v flag also terminates immediately with the same message. I have not touched the src file in a while, so I don't think that's the problem.